# An unexpected mushroom in my garden

Tags: taxonomy, species-identification, mycology

My grandma is a great fan of mushrooms and knows quite a lot about them. About 10 years ago, she started throwing out mushroom remnants in one special place, in order to grow her own mushrooms. In fact, for last three years we found some parasol mushrooms (*Macrolepiota procera*).

Today she found something, that nobody at home can classify. From what I searched, it might be  [*Cortinarius privignoides*](http://www.grzyby.net/cortinarius-privignoides.htm), but it is marked as almost extinct here in Poland, so I doubt this classification. Maybe you have seen this or know what it really is:

[image: Strange mushroom]

The hat is light brown with faint violet shades, the leg on the outside is partly violet too, but the inside is all white.

Some more photos:

[All three](http://hell.org.pl/~kamyk/mushroom/DSCN1448.JPG)

[The gills](http://hell.org.pl/~kamyk/mushroom/DSCN1450.JPG) are lighter brown, also with a violet tone

[The cut through the leg](http://hell.org.pl/~kamyk/mushroom/DSCN1453.JPG)

[The cut through the hat](http://hell.org.pl/~kamyk/mushroom/DSCN1454.JPG)

At my parents' house I found one more mushroom atlas, and a new candidate: Cortinarius traganus, but one thing is not right - the ones that I have don't have a smell and gassy webcap should smell and taste bad.

Comment: You might be better off asking this at gardening.stackexchange.com instead of Biology, unless a Botanist happens by here. :-)

Comment: Ooo! I did't even know about gardening :) Thanks!

Comment: If you know the german language, another good page is http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Redaktion_Biologie/Bestimmung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to MCM's advice I know for almost-certain that this is [*Lepista personata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepista_personata).